# Displaying Input file by user in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am able to create a structure to accept input from the user by using fileInput option. I want to view the same file as output.

```
library(shiny)

ui<-fluidPage(


fileInput(inputId = "ABC", label="Input File", multiple = FALSE, accept = NULL,
        width = NULL, buttonLabel = "Browse...",
        placeholder = "No file selected"),



dataTableOutput('XX')

)


server<-function(input, output){

output$XX<-renderDataTable(ABC)
#output$XX<-renderDataTable(iris_2)  


}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: see the example in `?fileInput`

Answer (score 0):

In server part of the app, change the output to:

```
output$XX<-renderDataTable(input$ABC)
```

In this way, the function knows which input it should use.

Comment: That won't work. `input$ABC` is not a table. One has to read the file before.

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `actionButton` and `observeEvent` control.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
    fileInput(inputId = "ABC", label = "Input File", multiple = FALSE, accept = NULL,
                width = NULL, buttonLabel = "Browse...",
                placeholder = "No file selected"),

    actionButton(inputId = "submit", label = "Submit"),
    dataTableOutput("XX")
  )

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent( input$submit, {
      data <- read.csv(input$ABC$datapath, header = TRUE, sep = ",")

      output$XX <- renderDataTable({
        datatable(data)
      })
    })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```